NextJs build run Error: Export encountered errors on following paths: /page: /
When I use npm run build in terminal on my nextjs application, I get this error. I'm having trouble deploying but I can host it locally.
What does this path page: / refer to?
I also made following changes in next.config.mjs but the result is same
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    eslint: {
        ignoreDuringBuilds: true
    }
};
export default nextConfig;`

